# Context based(?) RegEx search

Tags: python, regex

I need RegEx to find string based on it's first letters

Hello. I have string

```
ABDADBADBADBABDABDA
```

I want program to find string with mask

```
А*А*А*A.....
```

where "*" is group of any symbols except "A", but every "*" is the same group

I've tried

```
/((A[^A]+)+A)/g
```

but it matches the whole line

**Example**
Input:

```
AxxAxxAbxAx
```

Output:

```
AxxAxxA
```

Is there any intended RegEx solution or I have to use some code too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yon need to use backreferences for this.

For supplied example `A(.*?)A(?:\1A)*` should do the trick.

Here:

- `A` matches `A`,
- `(.*?)` matches everything till the next `A` and puts it into group #1,
- `(?:\1A)*` matches content of group #1 followed by `A` any number of times.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/dDiPGw/1).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a backreference:

```
import re

s = 'ABDADBADBADBABDABDA'

out = [m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(r'(?:(A[^A]+)\1)+A', s)]
```

Output: `['ADBADBA', 'ABDABDA']`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tUpAHg/1)